# IE encoding accented characters in javascript function with UrlEncode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, utf-8, urlencode

I have a javascript function that takes as argument a string that is UrlEncoded.

I'm using tags with href="javascript:..." (I know it's wrong to use this, but it's legacy code that i have to maintain... and changing this to onclick would break our API.)

Chrome and Firefox interpret the '%C3%A9' to 'é' correctly but ie interprets it as 'Ã©'.
If it was in onclick, i could explicitely unescape the string, but with the href="javascript.." IE interprets its before i can unescape it correctly.

```
<a href="javascript: alert('%C3%A9')">href</a>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('%C3%A9')">onclick</a>
```

See the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nCvsg/2/ (in IE).

Document is set to UTF8.
Is there a way to solve this in IE?

Comment: This can be more easily tested with `location = "javascript: alert('%C3%A9')";`. It seems like IE does not support UTF-8 there.

Comment: Does it have to be URL-encoded? This seem to work in all browsers: `alert('\u00E9')`, and even `alert('é')`. Don't know what your constraints are.

Comment: Is your document's charset UTF-8?

Comment: If I don't URL encode it it works yes. But I unfortunately need to keep stuff url encoded for now. 
Yes my document charset is UTF-8.